# ¿Cómo seleccionar lo que quieres en una QRegularExpression?

Tags: regex, qt, filtro

¿Cómo funcionan las Regular Expressions?

Tengo un programa en Qt donde tengo un modelo que carga una tabla de una Base de Datos. He creado 3 `QTableView` a partir del mismo modelo `QAbstractTableModel`pero en cada vista quiero filtrar unos datos diferentes, para ello uso [QSortFilteProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#details).

Ahí uso `filterRegExp : QRegExp`para filtrar los datos que quiero. Quedando algo así si quiero filtrar, en una columna (`colType`de mi modelo) de la tabla donde tengo letras, la `Q`:

```
    p_myQtypeProxyFilter->setSourceModel(p_myModel);
    p_myQtypeDetailTable->setModel(p_myQtypeProxyFilter);
    p_myQtypeProxyFilter->setFilterRegExp(QRegExp("Q",Qt::CaseInsensitive,
                             QRegExp::FixedString));
    p_myQtypeProxyFilter->setFilterKeyColumn(p_myModel->colType);
```

Nunca antes he usado Regular Expressions y no se bien como funcionan, ahí es donde tengo el problema.

**¿Cómo sería la expresión para que me muestre todas las letras menos la letra `Q` y `T`por ejemplo?**

He probado a poner algo así, pero no me saca nada en la tabla.

```
p_myQtypeProxyFilter->setFilterRegExp(QRegExp("\b[A-P][R-S][U-Z]\b",
                 Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::FixedString));
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu expresión regular espera **tres** letras. La primera, una entre A y P. La segunda, entre R y S, y la tercera entre U y Z.

Lo que buscas sería esta otra expresión regular:

```
\b[A-PR-SU-Z]\b
```

Es decir, todos los rangos de letras dentro de un solo par de corchetes.

Para verificar que esto funciona, y para ayudarte a entender mejor y depurar las expresiones regulares, [mira aqui](https://regex101.com/r/feuRpv/1). Es un servicio online que te perimte teclear una expresión regular, te la "interpreta" en una caja a la derecha (te explica qué significa cada símbolo) y te permite aplicarla sobre cadenas de prueba, mostrando los resultados.

Puede ser más sencillo usar esta otra:

```
\b[^QT\s]\b
```

Al poner un `^` como primer caracter dentro de los corchetes quieres signficar "su opuesto", así que ahora estamos pidiendo cualquier carácter excepto la Q, la T y el espacio (`\s` representa cualquier secuencia de blancos, tabuladores o retornos de carro).

Fíjate que esta otra forma no es completamente equivalente a la primera, pues la primera *sólo* permite las letras A-Z excepto T y Q, mientras que esta otra permite *cualquier carácter* (lo que incluye minúsculas, dígitos, etc.) salvo T y Q.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! He probado lo que me has dicho y no funcionaba, pero he visto que primero debía declarar la Expresión Regular antes de usarla y no poner las `\b`. Me queda así: `QString myRegExp=QString("[^QT]"); `    
 y luego
    `p_myYtypeProxyFilter->setFilterRegExp(QRegExp(myRegExp,Qt::CaseInsensitive));`. He intentado introducir también la `\s` pero no me lo reconoce en Qt :(

Comment: La `\b` es un "delimitador de palabra". Al poner uno delante y otro detrás, estás forzando a que sólo te detecte letras cuando esas letras individuales forman una sola palabra. O sea, en "HOLA" no detectaría nada, pero en "H O.L,A" sí que detectaría las cuatro letras. Supuse que eso era lo que querías y por eso no toqué esa parte.

Comment: Lo de la `\s` será porque quizás debas doblar la barra? `\\s` Esto suele ser necesario para poder introducir el caracter  \ dentro de una cadena en la mayoría de los lenguajes. Lo mismo aplica para la `\b`, que debería ser entonces `\\b`.

Comment: Lo único que yo tengo son letras sueltas, una en cada fila de la columna de la tabla. Igual el que no vaya es cosa de Qt, ya que la `\s` tampoco va supongo que igual no tiene ciertos caracteres registrados.

Comment: He probado a poner `\\s`y sí que me lo permite. Pero si dejo la casilla en blanco rechaza la fila, no me la muestra. Hay alguna Expresión regular que pueda añadir para que me muestre también esto?? Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: No te he entendido. Quieres que la expresión te seleccione filas cuando: a) bien tienen una letra mayúscula, salvo Q y T o b) cuando está vacia? ¿es eso?

Comment: Eso es, sí. Perdón, que no me he explicado muy bien.

Comment: @MAP Pues no tengo del todo claro tus especificaciones, pero creo que la expresión regular `^[^QT]*$` podría servirte. Mira [esta demostracion](https://regex101.com/r/IRCMBb/2/tests) en la que testeo cinco casos para ver que acepta los que debería aceptar y rechaza los que no.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda :)